# Single instance of an object

Tags: c++11, singleton, private-constructor

I'm trying to implement a singleton-like object with C++11. I got this example from another user.

It creates an object with the constructor and the copy constructor private and default, as well as an instance() function to return static object.

As I understand this should prevent the creation of two instances of this object. But as you can see in my main.cpp, I create two instances and it compiles and runs.

Is my object creation wrong or what? I don't get it.

object.hpp:

```
#ifndef OBJECT_H
#define OBJECT_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Object
{
private:
   Object() = default;
   Object(const Object&) = delete;
public:
   // Singleton in C++11
   static Object& instance() { static Object z; return z; }
};

#endif // OBJECT_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "object.hpp"

int main() 
{
    Object* object = new Object();
    object->instance();

    Object* object2 = new Object();
    object->instance();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is one of the weird rules of `= default`. If I use `Object(){}` instead of `Object() = default;` I get the desired result (`new` doesn't work.)

Comment: Be precise with the terminology : "It creates an object with the constructor and the copy...". Actually it creates a class :). And maybe naming a class "Object" is not the best idea because of that ;)

Comment: You're right, alfC, if I use `Object() {}` my compiler complains as well about the `new` command. Are there more weird rules concerning `= default`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your code in `main` won't compile. `Object` default constructor is private, so you won't be able to do :

Object* object = new Object();

Second, as `instance()` is static (means not related to any instance) there is no need to call it from an object, the class name suffices :

Object& theInstance = Object::instance();

Finally, the code of instance is :

```
static Object& instance()
{
    static Object z;
    return z;
}
```

It's OK. A `static` variable in a C++ function means that the object is instanciated once : when the function is ran for the first time. Then `z` won't be destroyed at the end of the function (contrary to other so-called local variables) and will be re-used for next calls of `instance`.

So at first call of `instance` :

- `z` is created
- `z` z is returned

At next calls :

- `z` is returned

A singleton is a class which implies only one instance will be created. You can verify the objects are the same with :

```
Object& a = Object::instance();
Object& b = Object::instance();

std::cout << &a << std::endl;
std::cout << &b << std::endl;
```

`a` and `b` should have the same memory adress.

This is the expected behaviour of a singleton : if the object construction function (`instance`) is called several times, the same instance will be returned.

So as you said, `instance` actually *prevents* the creation of two `Object`. Maybe you expected you program to return some error on the second call of `instance`. If you wan't this behaviour, you'll have to make it yourself using *expections* or returning `NULL`. Yet, The code you wrote shows the classic way singletons are done in C++.

Answer (score 2):

When I try to compile your code, I get a proper error from the compiler:

> main.cpp: error: calling a private constructor of class 'Object'
>           Object* ob1= new Object() ;

So I would not be able to create two objects using `new`.

Comment: Thanks, but also if I compile it on Ideone, it succedded. see http://ideone.com/1g4ziY

Comment: Icky.  I would file a bug report with them.

Comment: Yep, I will do that. And try out some different c++11 compilers. Thanks a lot!